# How to show SSRS 2016 report in iFrame at another SharePoint farm?

Tags: 2013, 2016, reporting-services

I'm trying to show an SharePoint 2016 integrated mode SSRS 2016 report in a SharePoint 2013 farm but I'm getting this error. These farms are at same domain.

[image]

I don't want to allow iFrames at SharePoint 2016 farm with

```
<WebPartPages:AllowFraming runat="server" />
```

Can I allow only one certain report to display in an iFrame? What can I do to show this report in a frame? Any ideas?

Comment: Did you found a solution ?

Answer (score 1):

You have an issue with the Cross Domain Policy implemented on web browsers.
You have few solutions to bypass that error.

1. Using **Page Viewer WebPart** *(https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Display-a-Web-page-on-a-SharePoint-page-by-adding-the-Page-Viewer-Web-Part-7f61feec-9b3d-4805-a960-07636ba59527)*.

*NB: Make sure the root url of the target SharePoint site, Web Application Url, SiteCollection Host named URL, SSRS root URL are in trusted zone from the internet options*

2. Add the following code in your masterpage at Site Collection level, usually before `</head>` tag

> `<WebPartPages:AllowFraming runat="server" />`

2. If you are using SSL certificate on SSRS, make sure your IIS Application related to your target Web Application is well configured with an SSL Certificate.
3. Another way would define the same domain for Reports and Sharepoint Sites in case you have two different FQDN *(eg. sharepoint.domain.com & reports.domain.com)*:

   - Adding a JavaScript routine on your reports and SharePoint sites to update the property **document.domain** to use the same common root/sub domain name **domain.com**

*NB: Your can only set the property with a parent domain name from the hierachy of the FQDN*

4. Hard Way: Moving SSRS under the same SharePoint domain. **NOT RECOMMENDED**

Answer (score 1):

You can try adding your domain to the allowed domain list.

To do this you have to go to:

1. Site Settings (Top-level site collection)
2. Select "HTML Field Security"
3. Choose "*Permit contributors to insert iframes from the following list of external domains into pages on this site*"
4. Insert domain in the allowed domains list

Source: [Working With iframe In SharePoint Server 2016 And SharePoint Online](http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/working-with-iframe-in-sharepoint-server-2016-and-sharepoint-online/)